# Error in WP Query. If variable is empty it is displaying previous post value

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-query, custom-field, loop

I have a wp-query that works however if a variable is empty then it seems to show the previous posts content. For example, if company name is empty then it shouldn't output anything however it shows the company name of the previous post. I'm really stumpped as to why this is happening.

code for 1 template is below:

```
else if ( isset( $atts['testimonial_template'] ) && ($atts['testimonial_template'] == 'standard_divi_4_column') ) { 
        $testimonial_layout_query = null;
        $testimonial_layout_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $testimonial_layout_output = '';
        if ( $testimonial_layout_query->have_posts() ) {
            $i = 1; // start counting the number of testimonials
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_gutters2 divi-testimonial">'; // open the first row for the testimonials 
            while ( $testimonial_layout_query->have_posts() ) : $testimonial_layout_query->the_post();
                $thumb = '';
                $testimonial_content = get_the_content();
                $testimonial_job_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_options_job_title', true );
                $company_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_options_url_text', true );
                $company_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_options_url', true );
                $testimonial_name = get_the_title();
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                $thumb = $thumb_url;
                }

                //$testimonial_layout_output .= $testimonial_content.'<br>'.$testimonial_job_title.'<br>'. $company_name.'<br>'.$company_url.'<br>'.$testimonial_name.'<br>'.$thumb.'<br>';


            $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 divi-testimonial_4"><div class="' . $module_class . ' et_pb_testimonial ' . $class . ' clearfix" style="'.$style.'">';
                if ( '' !== $thumb && 'on' === $show_thumbnail ) {
                    $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_testimonial_portrait" style="background-image: url('.$thumb_url .')"></div>';
                }
    $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_testimonial_description">
        <div class="et_pb_testimonial_description_inner"><p>
            ' . $testimonial_content . '</p>
            <strong class="et_pb_testimonial_author">' . $testimonial_name . '</strong>
            <p class="et_pb_testimonial_meta">';
            if ( ! empty( $testimonial_job_title ) ) {
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '' . $testimonial_job_title . '';
            }

            if ( ! empty($company_url) && ! empty($company_name)   ) {
                if ( ! empty( $testimonial_job_title ) ) {
                    $link_output = sprintf( ', <a href="%1$s"%3$s>%2$s</a>', esc_url( $company_url ),
                                    ( '' !== $company_name ? esc_html( $company_name ) : esc_html( $testimonial_name ) ),
                                    ( 'on' === $url_new_window ? ' target="_blank"' : '' )
                                    );
                } else {
                    $link_output = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"%3$s>%2$s</a>',
                                    esc_url( $company_url ),
                                    ( '' !== $company_name ? esc_html( $company_name ) : esc_html( $testimonial_name ) ),
                                    ( 'on' === $url_new_window ? ' target="_blank"' : '' )
                                    );
                }
                if ( '' !== $company_name ) {
                    //$company_name = $link_output;
                } else {
                    //$testimonial_name = $link_output;
                }
            }
            if ( isset($company_name)   ) {
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '' . $link_output .'';
        }

            $testimonial_layout_output .= '</p>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial_description_inner -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial_description -->
</div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial -->
</div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->';



                if($i % 4 == 0) {$testimonial_layout_output .= '</div><div class="clr"></div><div id="alt row" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_19 et_pb_gutters2 divi-testimonial">';}

                    $i++;

            endwhile; // End of the while loop.
            //wp_reset_query();
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '</div>';
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="clr"></div><style>.et_pb_column .et_pb_row { width:100%; }</style>';
        //} wp_reset_postdata();
        //return $testimonial_layout_output;

        } /*else {
            if ( et_is_builder_plugin_active() ) {
                include( ET_BUILDER_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/no-results.php' );
            } else {
                get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
            }
        }

        $posts = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        $output = $posts;

        return $output;*/
        //ob_flush();
        return $testimonial_layout_output;

    }
```

Would someone be able to tell my why $company_name shows the previous posts' company name if the post is empty. Also if the company url is empty it does NOT  get the previous posts url from what I can see.

Amended According to @Pim's answer. Still doesn't work right:

```
if ( isset( $atts['testimonial_template'] ) && ($atts['testimonial_template'] == 'standard_divi_4_column') ) { 
        $testimonial_layout_query = null;
        $testimonial_layout_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $testimonial_layout_output = '';
        if ( $testimonial_layout_query->have_posts() ) {
            $i = 1; // start counting the number of testimonials
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_gutters2 divi-testimonial">'; // open the first row for the testimonials 
            while ( $testimonial_layout_query->have_posts() ) : $testimonial_layout_query->the_post();
                $thumb = '';
                $testimonial_content = get_the_content();
                $testimonial_job_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_options_job_title', true );
                $company_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_options_url_text', true );
                $company_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_options_url', true );
                $testimonial_name = get_the_title();
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                $thumb = $thumb_url;
                }

                //$testimonial_layout_output .= $testimonial_content.'<br>'.$testimonial_job_title.'<br>'. $company_name.'<br>'.$company_url.'<br>'.$testimonial_name.'<br>'.$thumb.'<br>';


            $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 divi-testimonial_4"><div class="' . $module_class . ' et_pb_testimonial ' . $class . ' clearfix" style="'.$style.'">';
                if ( '' !== $thumb && 'on' === $show_thumbnail ) {
                    $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_testimonial_portrait" style="background-image: url('.$thumb_url .')"></div>';
                }
    $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="et_pb_testimonial_description">
        <div class="et_pb_testimonial_description_inner"><p>
            ' . $testimonial_content . '</p>
            <strong class="et_pb_testimonial_author">' . $testimonial_name . '</strong>
            <p class="et_pb_testimonial_meta">';
            if ( ! empty( $testimonial_job_title ) ) {
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '' . $testimonial_job_title . '';
            }

            if ( ! empty($company_url) && ! empty($company_name)   ) {
                if ( ! empty( $testimonial_job_title ) ) {
                    $link_output = sprintf( ', <a href="%1$s"%3$s>%2$s</a>', esc_url( $company_url ),
                                    ( '' !== $company_name ? esc_html( $company_name ) : esc_html( $testimonial_name ) ),
                                    ( 'on' === $url_new_window ? ' target="_blank"' : '' )
                                    );
                } else {
                    $link_output = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"%3$s>%2$s</a>',
                                    esc_url( $company_url ),
                                    ( '' !== $company_name ? esc_html( $company_name ) : esc_html( $testimonial_name ) ),
                                    ( 'on' === $url_new_window ? ' target="_blank"' : '' )
                                    );
                }
                if ( '' !== $company_name ) {
                    //$company_name = $link_output;
                } else {
                    //$testimonial_name = $link_output;
                }
            }
            if ( isset($company_name)   ) {
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '' . $link_output .'';
        }

            $testimonial_layout_output .= '</p>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial_description_inner -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial_description -->
</div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial -->
</div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->';



                if($i % 4 == 0) {$testimonial_layout_output .= '</div><div class="clr"></div><div id="alt row" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_19 et_pb_gutters2 divi-testimonial">';}

                    $i++;
                $thumb = '';
                $testimonial_content = '';
                $testimonial_job_title = '';
                $company_name = '';
                $company_url = '';
                $testimonial_name = '';
            endwhile; // End of the while loop.
            //wp_reset_query();
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '</div>';
            $testimonial_layout_output .= '<div class="clr"></div><style>.et_pb_column .et_pb_row { width:100%; }</style>';
        //} wp_reset_postdata();
        //return $testimonial_layout_output;

        } /*else {
            if ( et_is_builder_plugin_active() ) {
                include( ET_BUILDER_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/no-results.php' );
            } else {
                get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
            }
        }

        $posts = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        $output = $posts;

        return $output;*/
        //ob_flush();
        return $testimonial_layout_output;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the variables right before the end of the loop by inserting statements like `$company_name='';`. Since there's no check to make sure the variable becomes empty if the post_meta is empty, it will keep the previous one stored in the variable.

Comment: I added that right before the endwhile however it doesn't seem to have changed anything?